# Is it possible to use a Facebook like button from an iframe?

Tags: javascript, facebook, iframe, facebook-like

I have 2 websites in 2 different folders of the same server.

The first website is used as homepage, the second is used as iframe object of the first.

From the homepage is it possible to use the Facebook like button of the iframe object but display the domain of the first instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can like any URL you want in any place. You just have to specify the `data-href` attribute to the URL u want.

After including the Javascript SDK you can use the bellow sample code. Replace `<your_url>` with the URL u want to use.

Sample code:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="<your_url>" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```

You can also generate the code by going to Faccebook's [Like Button for the Web](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button) page.